# Can't find PredictionIO admin dashboard (migrating from PredictionIO 0.6.1 to 0.8.4)

Tags: java, mongodb, prediction, recommendation-engine, predictionio

I'm resuming to predictionio after a few months, last time I had used was 0.6.1 with mongodb, Java SDK, etc...

I believe there was a GUI driven interface to predictionio, Now the problem I'm facing is that, no where in the docs for new release they don't mention about any of GUI driven implementation.

Can anyone enlighten me what I'm missing ? or what have been changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin GUI is removed during the re-architect of 0.8.x. However, you can accomplish all the admin tasks through command line 
http://docs.prediction.io/resources/command-line/

-Isabelle